# How to use try-catch blocks in exception handling

Tags: java

When we use try-catch blocks, can we use multiple catch blocks with one try block?Is it a must to have catch block when a try block present?

Comment: I suggest you try it out yourself. You will learn a lot more that way.

Comment: You can have multiple catches for a single try , but not the other way around.This happens because one try can treat multiple exceptions, but you can't treat an exception twice.

Comment: Answers are yes (for catching different exception types) and no (try-finally, try-with-resources).

Answer (score 0):

Since different types of exceptions can be thrown from a single try block, multiple catch blocks can obviously be used with one try block to catch those exceptions.
It is a must to use catch block or finally block. If there's neither of them then it will be a compilation error. Therefore if there's a try block present and there's no finally block then it is a must to use catch block.

Comment: try-with-resources doesn't need a `catch` or `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways (for example):

```
try {
  // some code to access to a db

} catch (IOException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
}
```

Since Java 7 it is possible to use this way:

```
try {
  // some code to access to a db

} catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```